# Как правильно вызвав функцию с viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {} получить результат и вернуть обратно вызывающей стороне?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, return, viewmodel

С `MyActivity` вызываю `fun getSimpleDream(idItem)` которая должна вернуть объект полученный из базы данных.

Но не могу правильно сделать возврат значения в `MyActivity` так как `return` срабатывает до того как

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

    item = repository.getItem(itemId)

    Log.d("TAG","item 1 = "+ item.id)
}
```

присвоит значение в `item`.

Ниже код класса ViewModel:

```
class DreamsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: DreamsRepository

    init {
        val dreamsDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).dreamsDao()
        repository = DreamsRepository(dreamsDao)
    }

    fun getSimpleDream(itemId: Long): Dreams {

        var item = Dreams()

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            item = repository.getItem(itemId)

            Log.d("TAG","item 1 = "+ item.id)
        }

        Log.d("TAG"," item 2 = "+ item.id)

        return item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но не могу правильно сделать возврат значения в MyActivity так как return срабатывает до того как

ты запускаешь корутину но не используешь результат. 
Для таких задач есть [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) и `LiveData`.

Пример:

```
class DreamsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: DreamsRepository
    var simpleDream = MutableLiveData<Dreams>()

    init {
        val dreamsDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).dreamsDao()
        repository = DreamsRepository(dreamsDao)
    }

    fun getSimpleDream(itemId: Long) {

        var item = Dreams()

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            item = repository.getItem(itemId)
            simpleDream.postValue(item)
        }
    }
}
```

В примере я не показал для простоты, но не забывайте инкапсулировать `liveData`.
Пример в `MainActivity`:

```
viewModel.simpleDream.observe(this, Observer{ dream->
   //do anything with dreams at view layer
})
```

Деталей больше можете найти в документации. Настоятельно советую также посмотреть на остальные моменты:

- инициализация инстанса `Room` у `ViewModel`
- использование `context` в `ViewModel`
- неиспользование `onCleared()` для отмены корутины

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо за наглядный пример и за рекомендации.